# Hopf bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the scalar linear retarded equation (with infinite delay)
$$
x^{\prime}(t)=-ax(t)+b\int_{0}^{\infty}x(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau\;,
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $\tau\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, and $f$ is an appropriate delay kernel.  The book by Cushing covers a lot of these types of equations. I've always wondered why it doesn't make sense to talk about Hopf bifurcation in linear systems, for example. I know this is probably a trivial question, but I have to ask.